# How to calculate row wise trailing sum which resets on every next date in data in python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is what the data looks like

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-01-01','2021-01-01','2021-01-01','2021-01-01','2021-01-01',
                           '2021-01-02','2021-01-02','2021-01-02','2021-01-02','2021-01-02'],
                    'StP' : [500., 600., 700., 800., 900., 
                           500., 600., 700., 800., 900.],
                   'COI': [1., 2., 3., 4., 5.,
                           2., 3., 4., 5., 6.],
                   'POI': [3., 2., 4., 1., 5.,
                           2., 1., 3., 0., 5.],})

print(df)
```

| date | StP | COI | POI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 500.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 600.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 700.0 | 3.0 | 4.0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 800.0 | 4.0 | 1.0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 900.0 | 5.0 | 5.0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 500.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 600.0 | 3.0 | 1.0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 700.0 | 4.0 | 3.0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 800.0 | 5.0 | 0.0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 900.0 | 6.0 | 5.0 |

I need to create two columns (wl_COI and wl_POI) each derived from COI and POI respectively such that wl_COI has the sum of all entries with StP higher than the current row for a particular date. Similarly, wl_POI will have sum of all entries with StP lower than or equal to current row for a particular date. Sample desired output below -

| date | StP | COI | POI | wl_COI | wl_POI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 500.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 | 14.0 | 3.0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 600.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 | 12.0 | 5.0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 700.0 | 3.0 | 4.0 | 9.0 | 9.0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 800.0 | 4.0 | 1.0 | 5.0 | 10.0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 900.0 | 5.0 | 5.0 | 0.0 | 15.0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 500.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 | 18.0 | 2.0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 600.0 | 3.0 | 1.0 | 15.0 | 3.0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 700.0 | 4.0 | 3.0 | 11.0 | 6.0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 800.0 | 5.0 | 0.0 | 6.0 | 6.0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 900.0 | 6.0 | 5.0 | 0.0 | 11.0 |

I can do this very easily in excel but I am new to python and can't seem to figure out how to do this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


def compute_wl_cio(df, row):
    return sum(df['COI'].loc[np.logical_and(df['date']==row['date'], df['StP']>row['StP'])])

def compute_wl_pio(df, row):
    return sum(df['POI'].loc[np.logical_and(df['date']==row['date'], df['StP']<=row['StP'])])
```

And here's the output:

```
         date    StP  COI  POI  wl_COI  wl_POI
0  2021-01-01  500.0  1.0  3.0    14.0     3.0
1  2021-01-01  600.0  2.0  2.0    12.0     5.0
2  2021-01-01  700.0  3.0  4.0     9.0     9.0
3  2021-01-01  800.0  4.0  1.0     5.0    10.0
4  2021-01-01  900.0  5.0  5.0     0.0    15.0
5  2021-01-02  500.0  2.0  2.0    18.0     2.0
6  2021-01-02  600.0  3.0  1.0    15.0     3.0
7  2021-01-02  700.0  4.0  3.0    11.0     6.0
8  2021-01-02  800.0  5.0  0.0     6.0     6.0
9  2021-01-02  900.0  6.0  5.0     0.0    11.0
```

---

You can even do it in just a single function:

```
import operator 


def compute_wl(df, row, col, op):
    return sum(df[col].loc[np.logical_and(df['date']==row['date'], op(df['StP'], row['StP']))])


df['wl_COI'] = df.apply(lambda row: compute_wl(df, row, 'COI', operator.gt), axis=1)
df['wl_POI'] = df.apply(lambda row: compute_wl(df, row, 'POI', operator.le), axis=1)
```

Comment: The values for `wl_POI` do not appear to be correct.

Comment: @HenryEcker Yeah I missed that. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the values of `StP increases per row` for each `date`.

**Code**

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
gb = df.groupby('date')
df['wl_COI'] = gb.COI.transform('sum') - gb.COI.cumsum()
df['wl_POI'] = gb.POI.cumsum()
```

**Output**

```
    date        StP     COI POI wl_COI  wl_POI
0   2021-01-01  500.0   1.0 3.0 14.0    3.0
1   2021-01-01  600.0   2.0 2.0 12.0    5.0
2   2021-01-01  700.0   3.0 4.0 9.0     9.0
3   2021-01-01  800.0   4.0 1.0 5.0     10.0
4   2021-01-01  900.0   5.0 5.0 0.0     15.0
5   2021-01-02  500.0   2.0 2.0 18.0    2.0
6   2021-01-02  600.0   3.0 1.0 15.0    3.0
7   2021-01-02  700.0   4.0 3.0 11.0    6.0
8   2021-01-02  800.0   5.0 0.0 6.0     6.0
9   2021-01-02  900.0   6.0 5.0 0.0     11.0
```

Comment: You might want to include the assumptions about the data you've made for this solution.